# Will killing a Little Sister change the game's ending?

Tags: bioshock

I accidentally harvested a Little Sister, but it had been so long since my last save that I didn't want to reload, and just kept playing. Now I've found out that apparently the game's ending changes depending on whether you harvest or rescue the Little Sisters. Will one accidental kill ruin my chances at the "good" ending?

I tried to Google this, and the various answers out there are about 50/50 "Even a single kill will change the ending" or "You have to kill at least two or three before anything changes." Because of that, I'd appreciate some kind of source for the answer if possible.

ETA: I got the good ending despite killing one little sister on the PC version of the game.

Comment: You killed your little sister? You're a terrible person. ;)

Comment: No, no, don't worry, it was someone else's little sister. :)

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: I changed the title back to the original, because it's a bit less of a spoiler that way. When I started playing the game, I actually rather expected to get punished in the end somehow for saving the little sisters, because they were such creepy little monsters, and Atlas kept telling me to kill them. I didn't want to spoil which choice the game considers the "good" one right in the title.

Comment: This new title should make everyone happy.

Comment: Not what you asked, so just throwing it out as a comment, but you will miss out on the "Little Sister Savior" achievement/trophy. You didn't mention a system, so this may not apply.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be OK, as long as you avoid harvesting any more little sisters.

From the [IGN Game Guide](http://guides.ign.com/guides/793105/page_4.html) (my emphasis added):

> There are two possible endings for BioShock that depend on how you
>   treated little sisters throughout the game. If you choose to "harvest"
>   **more than one** little sister, you will get the bad BioShock ending. If,
>   however, you "harvest" **no more than one** little sister but "rescue" the
>   others, you will get the good BioShock ending.

However, there are two bad endings, depending upon how bad you have been.  Various [YouTube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3nBbo-uyZo) show them all.

Comment: Did they change that? I recall when the game first came out the stream of people who mentioned they killed one of them before they figured things out and got the "you are a horrible person" ending regardless of what they did from there on out.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.  I got the good ending and I rescued every little sister, as I have the Little Sister Savior trophy.  I was hoping that a quote from IGN would be correct, since the OP is correct - every thread on the Internet has people that claim they got the good ending or the bad ending with only harvesting a single little sister.

Comment: I'm quite close to the game's ending now, so I guess I'll be able to add one more point of anecdata to the discussion soon. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you save all the Little Sister you get the good ending (even if you kill one LS), but if you decide to harvest more than one or all, you will get the alternative endings. There are two, and each one depends if you saved some and harvested some or just decided to harvest all. Though the two negative endings are similar, the 'feeling' from the narrator changes - not the story. You release mayhem upon the real world if you decide to be a killer of Little Sisters.

Answer (score -2):

I have just completed the game with the good ending. I think I killed the second little sister, the first one the doctor asks you to save, but the second Atlas says "would you kindly kill the little monster."  Don't want to spoil, but I guess that kind of makes it okay.  If you get to Ryan you will understand.

Comment: i've completed the good ending and i don't kill a single one of them cause i imagine what you would do to a little girl to "harvest" would be horrifying but never having seen it (my dad has so i asked him but he can't remember). Also i don't remember the key phrase having any effect when it came to the Little Sisters (Atlas can go f*** himself if he think i'm harming them)