# My Little Sister is dead, should I get a new one or start over?

Tags: bioshock

In the level [Proving Grounds](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Proving_Grounds), you have to follow a Little Sister as she opens doors for you.

Mine just got killed near the end, Tenenbaum told me I could get a new one, but also state that one lost is already too much.

I systematically saved every Little Sister instead of harvesting them until now. Could I get a new one without any [impact on the end](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37109/will-killing-a-little-sister-change-the-games-ending) or should I load my save-game and try to escort her safely? What if she got killed again?

Comment: *And once again, a creepy title on Arqade.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tenenbaum just acts dramatically, but actually spawning and following another little sister doesn't impact the ending of the game (it's just boring to get back to the vent and call another one). I recall losing a couple of them in that level but saving all the others through all the game, and still getting the good ending.

Comment: thanks for the edit. i always misspell the word "through" :-/

Comment: Once you lose a Little Sister, it's worth going forward as far as you can and hacking all the cameras and turrets before going back and calling another Little Sister.  That way, you have as much help protecting her as possible when going forward again.  Also, I had the Static Discharge tonic equipped at the time and I think I shocked my first Little Sister to death by taking a few blows from splicers.  Best to avoid that.